# inserting data. one to one relationship. LinqToSql C#

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

How to insert the correct data? Here is one to one relationship. Should create an entry in the "Clients" with the same id as in the "details". Using the technology of linq-to-sql c#

[image: relationships]

Comment: Have you tried anything at all and if so, can you show the code and tell us where it fails?

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to SQL is no magic hat where you just put in your hand a pull out a rabbit which most people seem to think it is, since "nothing" (in your database at least) happens until you actually execute your command I don't see what your problem is, build up two new objects and use these.

There's probably ~5000 tutorials on this subject if that's what you're looking for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386941.aspx explains it perfectly

Answer (score 0):

> Should create an entry in the "Clients" with the same id as in the
>   "details". Using the technology of linq-to-sql c#

No, you add one entity to the other. Something like this:

```
using (var db = new myDataContext())

{
var newCLient = new client()
newclient.xx = ''
db.Clients.InsertOnSubmit(newClient)

var newDetail = new ...
newDetail.xx =  ''
Clientdetail.client = newClient

db.Submitchanges()

}
```

Notice in particular

- i am NOT using any id's
- Submitting the changes only once.